# Holiday - How to skip weekends when you apply for a leave

Tags: laravel-8

My holidays table is as follows

```
public function up() {
    Schema::create('holidays', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('created_by');
        $table->string('holiday_name');
        $table->date('start_date');
        $table->date('end_date');
        $table->text('description');
        $table->tinyInteger('publication_status');
        $table->tinyInteger('deletion_status')->default(0);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

My working_days table is as below

```
public function up() {
    Schema::create('working_days', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('updated_by');
        $table->string('day', 10);
        $table->tinyInteger('working_status')->comment('0 for holiday & 1 for working day');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

I store in my Holiday table a start_date = 2022-05-13 and an end_date = 2022-05-20. If I apply for a leave selecting start_date as 2022-05-13 and end_date as 2022-05-20 the code below is executed properly

```
if($monthly_holidays != null){
                return redirect()->route('leave.index')->with('exception', 'You select a holiday !');
    }
```

Saying You select a holiday
If I apply for a leave for non holiday dates the code below is executed properly and the dates are saved with the correct number of leaves (Sunday and Saturday are not counted and this is ok)

```
 if($monthly_holidays == null){
    $result = Leave::create($leave_application +['num_days' => $days] +['reason' =>request('reason')] + ['created_by' => auth()->user()->id]);
            
    $inserted_id = $result->id;

    if (!empty($inserted_id)) {
        return redirect()->route('leave.index')->with('message', 'Add successfully.');
    }
    return redirect()->route('leave.index')->with('exception', 'Operation failed !');

   }
```

However If I select Sunday and Saturday my code below does not work the way I should expect because  Sunday and Saturday dates are saved as leaves

```
 if($weekly_holidays != null){
    
        foreach ($weekly_holidays as $weekly_holiday) {
            if ($sdates == $weekly_holiday['day'] && $edates == $weekly_holiday['day']) {
                return redirect()->route('leave.index')->with('exception', 'You select a holiday !');
            }
    }
```

The complete code is as follows

```
    public function store(Request $request) {
    
    $sdates = date("D", strtotime($request->start_date));
    $edates = date("D", strtotime($request->end_date));
    
    $leave_application = $this->validate($request, [
        'leave_category_id' => 'required',
        'start_date' => 'required',
        'end_date' => 'required',
    ]);

    $start_date = Carbon::parse(request('start_date'));
    $end_date = Carbon::parse(request('end_date'));

    $days = $start_date->diffInWeekdays($end_date);

    $weekly_holidays = WorkingDay::where('working_status', 0)
        ->get(['day'])
        ->toArray();

 $monthly_holidays = Holiday::where('start_date', '=', $request->start_date)->where('end_date', '=',$request->end_date)
        ->first(['start_date','end_date']);

 if($monthly_holidays == null){
    $result = Leave::create($leave_application +['num_days' => $days] +['reason' =>request('reason')] + ['created_by' => auth()->user()->id]);
            
    $inserted_id = $result->id;

    if (!empty($inserted_id)) {
        return redirect()->route('leave.index')->with('message', 'Add successfully.');
    }
    return redirect()->route('leave.index')->with('exception', 'Operation failed !');

   }

if($weekly_holidays != null){
    
        foreach ($weekly_holidays as $weekly_holiday) {
            if ($sdates == $weekly_holiday['day'] && $edates == $weekly_holiday['day']) {
                return redirect()->route('leave.index')->with('exception', 'You select a holiday !');
            }
        
    }
        
    }
  
   
  if($monthly_holidays != null){
                return redirect()->route('leave.index')->with('exception', 'You select a holiday !');
    }
        
}
```

I am not able to figure out how to skip weekends. Weekend like sun and sat still recorded in the leave table. please help

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the Holiday table to store just holiday date to make it simple

```
    public function up() {
    Schema::create('holidays', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('created_by');
        $table->string('holiday_name');
        $table->date('holiday_date');
        $table->text('description');
        $table->tinyInteger('publication_status');
        $table->tinyInteger('deletion_status')->default(0);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

and made some changes to my store methods as follows

```
public function store(Request $request) {
    
    $sdates = date("D", strtotime($request->start_date));
    $edates = date("D", strtotime($request->end_date));
    
    $leave_application = $this->validate($request, [
        'leave_category_id' => 'required',
        'start_date' => 'required',
        'end_date' => 'required',
    ]);

    $start_date = Carbon::parse(request('start_date'));
    $end_date = Carbon::parse(request('end_date'));

    $days = $start_date->diffInWeekdays($end_date);

    $weekly_holidays = WorkingDay::where('working_status', 0)
        ->get(['day'])
        ->toArray();

        if($weekly_holidays != null){

            foreach ($weekly_holidays as $weekly_holiday) {
                if ($sdates == $weekly_holiday['day'] || $edates == $weekly_holiday['day']) {
                    return redirect()->route('leave.index')->with('exception', 'You select a weekend !');
                }               
               }                
        }

        $monthly_holidays = Holiday::where('holiday_date', '=', $request->start_date)
        ->first(['holiday_date']);
        
        
   if($monthly_holidays == null){
    $result = Leave::create($leave_application +['num_days' => $days] +['reason' =>request('reason')] + ['created_by' => auth()->user()->id]);
            
    $inserted_id = $result->id;

    if (!empty($inserted_id)) {
        return redirect()->route('leave.index')->with('message', 'Add successfully.');
    }
    return redirect()->route('leave.index')->with('exception', 'Operation failed !');

   }
  
   
   if($monthly_holidays != null){
                return redirect()->route('leave.index')->with('exception', 'You select a holiday !');
    }
        
}
```

When I mistakenly set my leave on Sunday or Saturday and submit. My exception works and says You select a weekend